# Memory allocation error unity at compile time

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory, memory-management, crash

Quite frequently I get a memory allocation error in unity at compile time.
Afaik this can be due to a very high number of assets, or due to an asset that might be too large.

I observed that most of the time the amount of memory that produces the problem is the same:
134217728B with 16 alignment.

Note the 'most of the time', not always.

1.- Is there a way to know what specific asset is related to the amount of memory that failed to be allocated in the crash?
2.- Is there a way to evaluate the amount of ram memory your machine might need according to the size of a project, the number of assets or any other relevant parameter?

The crash is related with the lack of me for some compilation task. My point is that even if this kind of errors are hard to identify/debug solve, the fact the the size to allocate is almost always the same (in this case `134217728`), there could be some hint to get to know the asset resposible or some proposal of action to prevent the crash.

**Edit:**

Up to what I am researching, reading the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity4-1.html?_gl=1*d9x16x*_ga*MTcwODAyODg1LjE1NDQyMDI3NTk.*_ga_1S78EFL1W5*MTYyMzY3MTE2OC40Ny4xLjE2MjM2NzEyOTMuNQ..&_ga=2.180090660.1677932774.1623658609-170802885.1544202759), this seems to be the key: "Consider loading operations. If a large number of temporary objects are generated during a heavy Asset-loading operation, and those objects are referenced until the operation completes, then the garbage collector is unable to release those temporary objects and the managed heap needs to expand – even though many of the objects it contains will be released a short time later."

The key would then be to identify the problematic assets and slice those down for smoother memory allocation.

Image and relevant part of the log below.

**Image:**

[image]

**Relevant part of the Editor.log:**

Reloading assemblies after finishing script compilation.

Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 1 failed - Could not get memory for large allocation 134217728.
DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 2 failed - Could not get memory for large allocation 134217728.
DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 3 failed - Could not get memory for large allocation 134217728.
DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 4 failed - Could not get memory for large allocation 134217728.
DynamicHeapAllocator out of memory - Could not get memory for large allocation 134217728!
Could not allocate memory: System out of memory!
Trying to allocate: 134217728B with 16 alignment. MemoryLabel: DynamicArray
Allocation happened at: Line:75 in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Utilities/dynamic_array.h
Memory overview

[ ALLOC_DEFAULT ] used: 1759593661B | peak: 0B | reserved: 2040112693B
[ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 16777216B
[ ALLOC_TEMP_BACKGROUND_JOB ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 1048576B
[ ALLOC_GFX ] used: 9760199558B | peak: 0B | reserved: 9803569966B
[ ALLOC_CACHEOBJECTS ] used: 547232668B | peak: 0B | reserved: 810108412B
[ ALLOC_TYPETREE ] used: 102395080B | peak: 0B | reserved: 119537664B
[ ALLOC_PROFILER ] used: 63528720B | peak: 63834568B | reserved: 67108864B
[ ALLOC_PROFILER_EDITOR ] used: 22288B | peak: 31520B | reserved: 1048576B
[ ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD ] used: 32768B | peak: 0B | reserved: 23199744B
Could not allocate memory: System out of memory!
Trying to allocate: 134217728B with 16 alignment. MemoryLabel: DynamicArray
Allocation happened at: Line:75 in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Utilities/dynamic_array.h
Memory overview

[ ALLOC_DEFAULT ] used: 1759593661B | peak: 0B | reserved: 2040112693B
[ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 16777216B
[ ALLOC_TEMP_BACKGROUND_JOB ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 1048576B
[ ALLOC_GFX ] used: 9760199558B | peak: 0B | reserved: 9803569966B
[ ALLOC_CACHEOBJECTS ] used: 547232668B | peak: 0B | reserved: 810108412B
[ ALLOC_TYPETREE ] used: 102395080B | peak: 0B | reserved: 119537664B
[ ALLOC_PROFILER ] used: 63528720B | peak: 63834568B | reserved: 67108864B
[ ALLOC_PROFILER_EDITOR ] used: 22288B | peak: 31520B | reserved: 1048576B
[ ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD ] used: 32768B | peak: 0B | reserved: 23199744B

**Edit: I post also the rest of the log, in case it might be of any help**

[Performance] WebView.DoCefMessages                   :     2459 samples, Peak.   228 ms (374.1x), Avg.   609 us, Total. 1.497 s (0.0%)
[Performance] WebView.CheckCurlRequests               :      699 samples, Peak.   230 us (103.8x), Avg.  2.22 us, Total. 1.550 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] License.Tick                            :   175393 samples, Peak.  12.0 ms (6922.7x), Avg.  1.73 us, Total. 303.2 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] UnityConnect.Tick                       :    94325 samples, Peak.  3.24 ms (490.2x), Avg.  6.61 us, Total. 623.6 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] PackageManager::RunRequestSynchronously :        4 samples, Peak.  37.4 ms (3.5x), Avg.  10.7 ms, Total. 42.74 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] ProjectBrowser.OnGUI                    :     2654 samples, Peak.  5.39 s (959.3x), Avg.  5.62 ms, Total. 14.91 s (0.2%)
[Performance] SceneHierarchyWindow.OnGUI              :    21680 samples, Peak.  5.05 s (2197.0x), Avg.  2.30 ms, Total. 49.86 s (0.6%)
[Performance] InspectorWindow.OnGUI                   :     7630 samples, Peak.  3.12 s (208.8x), Avg.  14.9 ms, Total. 113.9 s (1.3%)
[Performance] GameView.OnGUI                          :   426770 samples, Peak.   535 ms (897.9x), Avg.   596 us, Total. 254.5 s (2.9%)
[Performance] ConsoleWindow.OnGUI                     :     2494 samples, Peak.  32.8 ms (64.9x), Avg.   505 us, Total. 1.260 s (0.0%)
[Performance] SceneView.OnGUI                         :   152351 samples, Peak.   310 ms (66.7x), Avg.  4.64 ms, Total. 707.3 s (8.2%)
[Performance] SceneButtons.OnGUI                      :      122 samples, Peak.   496 ms (115.2x), Avg.  4.31 ms, Total. 525.6 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] ApplicationTickTimer                    :   354737 samples, Peak.   499 s (40957.4x), Avg.  12.2 ms, Total. 4.320 ks (49.9%)
[Performance] VCProvider                              :   354738 samples, Peak.   447 us (318.4x), Avg.  1.41 us, Total. 498.5 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] MonoCompiler.Tick                       :    30126 samples, Peak.  16.2 s (25084.8x), Avg.   644 us, Total. 19.40 s (0.2%)
[Performance] Internal_SwitchSkin                     :   354737 samples, Peak.  28.7 us (744.5x), Avg.  38.5 ns, Total. 13.67 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] Collab.Tick                             :    93099 samples, Peak.   528 us (292.8x), Avg.  1.80 us, Total. 167.9 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] WebView.Tick                            :   172938 samples, Peak.   443 ms (5178.0x), Avg.  85.5 us, Total. 14.79 s (0.2%)
[Performance] CurlRequest.Tick                        :    56494 samples, Peak.  20.9 ms (12761.9x), Avg.  1.64 us, Total. 92.53 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] SceneBackgroundTask.Tick                :    38635 samples, Peak.  62.4 us (268.6x), Avg.   232 ns, Total. 8.975 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] Scheduler.Tick                          :   298816 samples, Peak.  2.29 ms (63.6x), Avg.  36.1 us, Total. 10.77 s (0.1%)
[Performance] RepaintAllProfilerWindows               :    11972 samples, Peak.  1.14 ms (674.7x), Avg.  1.68 us, Total. 20.15 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] PlayerUpdates.Tick                      :    93092 samples, Peak.   455 us (19.1x), Avg.  23.8 us, Total. 2.213 s (0.0%)
[Performance] GlobalCallbacks                         :   354737 samples, Peak.   291 ms (6080.2x), Avg.  47.8 us, Total. 16.96 s (0.2%)
[Performance] EditorAnalytics.Tick                    :    24515 samples, Peak.   290 ms (20095.9x), Avg.  14.4 us, Total. 353.7 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] GI.Tick                                 :      937 samples, Peak.   860 us (22.1x), Avg.  38.9 us, Total. 36.46 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] Video.Update                            :   354737 samples, Peak.   306 us (403.3x), Avg.   760 ns, Total. 269.5 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] UnitySynchronization.ExecuteTasks       :     4630 samples, Peak.  6.44 ms (899.0x), Avg.  7.16 us, Total. 33.14 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] Package.AsyncRequest                    :       10 samples, Peak.   108 us (8.9x), Avg.  12.1 us, Total. 121.0 us (0.0%)
[Performance] PreloadManager                          :   249203 samples, Peak.   357 us (58.7x), Avg.  6.08 us, Total. 1.516 s (0.0%)
[Performance] SceneTracker                            :   354737 samples, Peak.  2.12 s (6423.6x), Avg.   330 us, Total. 116.9 s (1.4%)
[Performance] ConsoleLog.Tick                         :    30117 samples, Peak.   261 us (88.0x), Avg.  2.97 us, Total. 89.44 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] HierarchyWindow.Tick                    :    36792 samples, Peak.   131 ms (1620.4x), Avg.  81.0 us, Total. 2.979 s (0.0%)
[Performance] Inspector.Tick                          :    36784 samples, Peak.   222 ms (14.4x), Avg.  15.4 ms, Total. 565.2 s (6.5%)
[Performance] Tooltip.Tick                            :    83723 samples, Peak.   221 ms (3980.2x), Avg.  55.4 us, Total. 4.641 s (0.1%)
[Performance] RequestRepaintForPanels                 :   351040 samples, Peak.   548 us (75.9x), Avg.  7.22 us, Total. 2.533 s (0.0%)
[Performance] UpdateSceneIfNeeded                     :   351040 samples, Peak.   498 s (57935.4x), Avg.  8.60 ms, Total. 3.019 ks (34.9%)
[Performance] UpdateVideoTextures                     :     4105 samples, Peak.  1.30 us (2.8x), Avg.   460 ns, Total. 1.887 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] PackageImporter.Tick                    :    30065 samples, Peak.   320 us (540.3x), Avg.   593 ns, Total. 17.82 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] InspectorBackground.Tick                :    38566 samples, Peak.   198 us (244.3x), Avg.   810 ns, Total. 31.23 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] ChangeLayoutIfNeeded                    :   354737 samples, Peak.   124 ms (72989.2x), Avg.  1.70 us, Total. 604.1 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] AsyncReadManager.ForceCloseFiles        :     6517 samples, Peak.  11.7 ms (1414.4x), Avg.  8.26 us, Total. 53.82 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] InactiveGI.Tick                         :     1235 samples, Peak.   977 us (24.5x), Avg.  39.9 us, Total. 49.28 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] RepaintAll                              :     3697 samples, Peak.  37.3 ms (647.1x), Avg.  57.7 us, Total. 213.4 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] AnimationWindow.OnGUI                   :       41 samples, Peak.  21.8 ms (14.9x), Avg.  1.46 ms, Total. 59.86 ms (0.0%)
[Performance] ConsolePro3Window.OnGUI                 :       55 samples, Peak.   158 ms (34.7x), Avg.  4.54 ms, Total. 249.8 ms (0.0%)

Comment: hm that's already allocated ca 2GB + the new 128MB ..   and 9GB GFX ... that's pretty much ... are you using a 32bit version of Unity? Afaik there is a hard limit on 2GB RAM for the 32 bit version .. see e.g. [Maximum amount of RAM on OS X and Windows?](https://forum.unity.com/threads/maximum-amount-of-ram-on-os-x-and-windows.162848/)

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. I am using 64 bit version

Comment: However your link talks regarding RAM for an executable to run stably. That would be useful also for me to know also, but just to clarify, my question talks about development in editor. Not sure if both scenarios are independent though, but to narrow that my question, its regarding a crash in editor at compile time, an my question is to evaluate the problem and the hardware needs for that case :)

Comment: I don't think its on compile time but rather on asset import time ... you seem to either have a vast amount of assets or simply very huge once in your project and reach a point where your PC can not handle it

Comment: at compile time I mean when I change code in the project and do ctrl + R. Guess that in that case import is done also. Exactly as you say that seem to be the case. My point is if it would be possible to locate the possible problematic asset, or evaluate the memory need to handle the situation...

Comment: oh in general you don't need to do ctrl + R everytime (Refreshes all Assets => changed assets get reimported)

Comment: but if I change code, I need the project to compile....is it possible to separate code compile from asset import/refresh?

Comment: Usually Unity should track that itself ... after changing a script, saving and coming back to the Editor usually Unity checks for changes and recompiles automatically

Comment: yes, in case Edit->Preferences->General->AutoRefresh is enabled. Which is not my case because I like/need to choose when to compile due to large compile times

Comment: As you mentioned this does not crash all the time, you could force a refresh and view the memory profiler, then see if there are any significant spikes or outliers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the memory profiler was a very useful tip. If there are any spikes or outliners how could I associate those with the the specific asset producing them?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I would check out the [`docs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerMemory.html) on the profiler. The more in-depth package should allow you to tell exactly what type of asset is causing the spike or even possibly exactly which asset it is.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay To be more specific, check out the bottom of the page I have linked. Specifically the `Detailed view`. It gives you a breakdown of everything at a current point in the project.

Comment: thanks @TEEBQNE, I gave it a shot. I might yet need to dig a bit more for a good interpretation of the profiler results. For the moment, although I find it quite useful for an overall overview, I find it difficult to relate a specific asset with an specific spike, so as the same to find the asset involved in the crash for the specific alloc amount 134217728.

Comment: Have you installed the package instead if the basic profiler? It should breakdown every asset and it's memory consumption at specific times. The basic profiler is more of an overview. The packages docs can be found [`here`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.memoryprofiler@0.2/manual/index.html)

Comment: yes I tried that also, but seems to be for runtime profile, as you can capture snapshots that show you info regarding the mem alloc profile, but this campture button is disabled in compile time, when my crash occurs. In case it was disabled I might take some random captures and give them a look, but as far as I checked, no chance to do that. Even if there was that chance, there is no kind of "continuous" profiling as the built in unity, so I would be lucky a concrete snapshot revealed the problem. Thanks though :)

Comment: My last chance will be to remove lots of the not critical assets and check if the crash does not occur anymore, that will presumably be solution, the same as would be increasing the memory of the working hardware. However, I would love to find the kind of explanation that explains the problem clearly, if it is some asset or if it is the whole of the project how to evaluate the hardware needs :)

Comment: What Unity version are you using for this project? It might be internal issue, which was already fix in some patch

Comment: Unity 2018.4.12f1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Unity (on its 32-bit standalone) only allows allocation of 4 GB of RAM per player per scene. This means that you can't render more than 4 GB of sprites (allocation) without an Abort Trap. The actual practical limit on 32-bit devices (for each player's individual render) is quite often much lower than the threshold. You can expect 1.5 to 2 GB of RAM usage for the following reasons:

- Limited address space
- Memory fragmentation
- Asynchronous rendering of GUI and debug tools

I would first recommend installing 64-bit Unity standalone if available.

If you want a solution that doesn't involve updates:

To combat this problem, Unity provides a built-in tool called PackingTags/SpritePacker. You can render only what is in the scene by packing sprites into hierarchies. If you leave the scene, they are unrendered. If you aren't looking at a set of sprites (perhaps because the world doesn't render completely), then your RAM consumption will be drastically reduced. Tag grouping should definitely be used when possible. This also reduces non-unions (which look like bugs in your game).

To answer your questions:

1. To check which asset is causing you trouble, let me refer you to the [Memory Profiler Module](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerMemory.html) available in the Unity Docs. Profiler Module shows you what parts of your system are being used for which sprite renders. If you delete sprites and run your script (one-by-one, I'm afraid), it is a brute-force, guaranteed way to check which sprites are abusing memory.
2. I would assume that the result that #1's module spits out to you would be the amount of memory your system needs (at the minimum). I would add a few hundred megabytes to give users the chance to decide whether their system can handle the game or not. It would suck for a minimum system to freeze.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I gave shot to the memory profiler, but was not able to relate the amount of memory to allocate that produces the crash with an specific asset.

Comment: According to what I read [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity4-1.html) the problem is this one, from the link provided:

Comment: "However, if a large object is allocated and there is insufficient contiguous free space to accommodate the object, as illustrated above, the Unity memory manager performs two operations.

First, if it has not already done so, the garbage collector runs. This attempts to free up enough space to fulfill the allocation request.
If, after the GC runs, there is still not enough contiguous space to fit the requested amount of memory, the heap must expand."

Comment: As far as I understand, at compiletime, unity performs all the memory allocation for your project, according to this fragmentation, if your project is big, and you have lots of assets form whom some of them might be big (not necessarily sprites as you mention), the system runs out of memory and crashes thowing the error shown in my question. What would be awesome is that if some asset is making this error prone, or when some same asset is mayorly risponsible for the crash (same alloc amount seems to correspond to same asset), to have which asset is this, or which one is the asset to blame

Comment: I don't think this tooling is currently available, rustyBucketBay. If I were you, I would use the closest tooling to what is currently accessible: https://thegamedev.guru/unity-memory/profiler-module-metrics-programatically/ GameDev Guru does a good job at explaining the attachment of memory modules to assets.